# modify response in express/nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express

i am making multiple streamdata in Nodejs using express.

this is how i make a url:

```
app.get('/temp/1', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello, i am not modified')
})
```

my question is: is it possible to modify the response of that url?

i tried like this:

```
app.get(/modify/1, function(req, res){  
    app.get('/temp/1', function(req, res){
       res.send('hello, i am modified')
    })    
  res.send('done');
}
```

So i would think that the response is changed, but nothing happens actually.
is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: https://github.com/mo22/express-modify-response https://github.com/axiomzen/express-interceptor

Comment: thanks, but can you give me some example how to apply to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [`express-modify-response`](https://github.com/mo22/express-modify-response):

```
const modifyResponse = require('express-modify-response');
...

let modify = modifyResponse(
  function(req, res)       { return true }, // always modify the response
  function(req, res, body) { return 'hello, i am modified' } // the new response
);

app.get('/temp/1', modify, function(req, res){
  res.send('hello, i am not modified')
})
```

**EDIT**: second attempt. You have an endpoint `/temp/1` that sends a particular response, and you want an endpoint `/modify/1` that will take that response and modify it.

This calls for some abstraction:

```
function someFunction(id) {
  return 'hello, i am not modified';
}

app.get('/temp/1', function(req, res) {
  res.send(someFunction(1));
});

app.get('/modify/1', function(req, res) {
  let value = someFunction(1);

  // Remove the word `not`.
  value = value.replace(/not /, '');

  res.send(value);
});
```

So both handlers use the same function, that provides the actual output, but `/modify/1` modifies the output before returning it to the client.

Comment: thanks, this method words, but not the way i want it. i want to modify the response manually. for example, i go to this url ('/modify/1') and this url modifies ('temp/1') url. 

the code above modifies it directly without doing anything.

Comment: It sounds like you should consider restructuring your application so the code that is used for `/temp/1` can be called by the handler for `/modify/1` directly, without having to perform "internal" requests or modify responses.

Comment: can you please give an example how to do it. thank you.

Comment: Your code works fine. i think i am not explaining very well. this code modifies the response in ('modify/1'). i am trying to modify the response in ('temp/1') by calling another api like ('modify/1').

Comment: I'm sure you can switch the route handlers in my example so it works the other way around?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145034/discussion-between-user2959870-and-robertklep).